# uploading file to subdomain on same server-permission denied

Tags: php, linux, apache, file-upload, putty

I'm using this code to upload file to my server. It works just fine if I am uploading to same server but it does not upload if I am uploading to subdomain which is in the same server but different cpanel and everything.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $url = 'http://www.indiancinemagallery.com/gallery/vaani-kapoor/Vaani-Kapoor-at-Radio-Mirchi-Stills-(9)9678.jpg';
    $img = '/home/path_A/something/test/flower.gif';
    file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
?>
```

I have given correct path for subdomain.

If I give path of same server from where file is being executed it will upload otherwise it will not upload. The main problem is `mysql` is there in main server so i want to execute the file from main server and store the photo in subdomain and update the details in main server.

Warning: (flower.gif: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Comment: @panoptical there is no error message

Comment: Its because user permission, by default you do not have permission to write on other users directory just by path. But if you could manage to change usergroup of that folder. It will allow you to write in that folder

Comment: @AnkitPisei have never done can u please give some more details how to do that

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a file permission problem. Your script must have write access to wherever `$img` points to on the server.

Can you try adding the following at the top of your PHP script to see what, if any, errors/warnings that PHP is throwing?

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

That should tell you if it is failing to write to the file and give you some info.

If after changing permissions, you still cannot write to that location, I imagine it is enforced by your web server management software (Web Host Manager, cPanel, etc.) and how it configures the file space. At that point, you might want to try using PHP's FTP functions (preferably SFTP for security): http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ssh2.php

Comment: how to solve this. i had this doub t but i checked the subdomain and foun that it is 755

Comment: I added some code to use to see what PHP says about the problem.

Comment: Warning: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/xxxx/tey2.php on line 9

Comment: So, the file permissions appear to be the problem. You could try setting the permissions to 775 or higher.

Comment: i think its domain issue i have to assign owner of that file anyway

Comment: Yeah, I would imagine that the way cPanel/WHM set things up it won't allow you to write from one shared account to another. That would indeed seem like a big security vulnerability. You might need to use PHP's FTP functions to write across the two sites.

Comment: I updated my answer with a suggestion about FTP/SFTP.